# Emails not centering on iphone 5 and 6

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, email

I'm trying to get my emails to be centered when they're opened on mobile devices. It seems like it's working on all devices right now except on the iPhone. I've tested it on the 5 (it skews left) and the 6/6s (it skews right). The issue looks like it's only happening on the native mail app. 
We'll be moving to responsive emails in the future, but for now we're using these HTML image/table based emails (unfortunately).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<title>Email Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="title" content="Email Title">
<meta name="description" content="Email Title">

<style media="all" type="text/css">
    table img {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        width: 100% !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    .ReadMsgBody {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td {
        line-height: 100%
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        padding: 0;
    }

    table td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 10px; color: gray; font-family: Verdana, Arial, San-Serif, Geneva;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">

            <table width="640" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0;">
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Shop</a></font>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="padding:0;">
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Women's</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Men's</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Apartment</a></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>


            <!--Dynamic header-->
            <!-- logo -->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                <tr>
                    <td width="640">
                        <a href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="" width="640" height="45" style="display:block">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--Begin Email-->

            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="" style="display:block;" border="0" alt="graphic1">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                



            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="spacing">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like I've tried just about everything, including using a `<center>` tag, but nothing makes it budge.

ETA: Here is a screenshot of what it looks like on iOS 9
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/944SZ.png)

Comment: what's not centering? the entire table? or something in the table?

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked or not!  Curious either way...

Answer (score 0):

First, Not entirely sure what you mean by "not centering". If it's for the whole table not centering to the screen, take a look at your inline styling. There are a few set widths and heights; I strongly discourage inline styling for many reasons. Try to get rid of all of them and instead change width to percentages and see what happens.

The table usually fits within the container unless the content inside the table is set to be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned that your team was 'moving to responsive emails in the future' but perhaps this a much easier transition than you would expect and would most likely solve your issue...

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) makes responsive design as well as 'centering' ridiculously easy.

Comment: I hear ya, but unfortunately it's a politics issue, not so much a development issue. We're all waiting for the day we can code a responsive email around here!

Comment: Office politics suck haha after looking over your code again, did you try adding margin:auto to the body element? All i see is margin:0...

Answer (score 0):

You could just change all the hard coded widths to be a percentage instead of a set value.   If you replace all 640px with 100%, then it looks fine on my iPhone 6s+.     Then you can limit the max-width to whatever you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

<title>Email Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="title" content="Email Title">
<meta name="description" content="Email Title">

<style media="all" type="text/css">
    table img {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        width: 100% !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        max-width: 640px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .ReadMsgBody {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .ExternalClass p,
    .ExternalClass span,
    .ExternalClass font,
    .ExternalClass td {
        line-height: 100%
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        padding: 0;
    }

    table td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #ffffff; font-size: 10px; color: gray; font-family: Verdana, Arial, San-Serif, Geneva;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">

            <table width="100%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding:0;">
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Shop</a></font>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="padding:0;">
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Women's</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Men's</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
                                    <font face="Helvetica, sans-serif" style="font-size:12px; color:#b4b4b4;font-weight:400;"><a style="color:#b4b4b4;" href="">Apartment</a></font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>


            <!--Dynamic header-->
            <!-- logo -->
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                        <a href=""><img src="" border="0" alt="" width="100%" height="45" style="display:block">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--Begin Email-->

            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="">
                            <img src="" style="display:block;" border="0" alt="graphic1">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                



            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="spacing">
                <tr>
                    <td height="10px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Updated answer to reflect margin and max width

Comment: Just tried this but am still having issues. It looks good on iOS 8 but on iOS 9 the whole thing skews to the right on the native mobile app.

Comment: Can you add an image of what it looks like.   it looked fine on my  6+ on ios9.

Comment: I added a screenshot in my original comment above!